# Django Posts Not Working:

Tags: ajax, django, jquery

I am using Django 1.2.3 to develop a site. My ajax get requests work fine but the post requests work in development mode (127.0.0.1:8000) but not when I push the site into production using apache + nginx.

Here is an example

urls.py:

```
(r'api/newdoc/$', 'mysite.documents.views.newdoc'),
```

views.py

```
def newdoc(request):
    # only process POST request
    if request.is_ajax():
        data= dict(request.POST)

                # save data to db



    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps([True]))
```

in javascript:

```
$.post("/api/newdoc/", {data : mydata}, function(data) { alert(data);}, "json");
```

my alert is never called .... this is a problem because i want to sanitize this data via a django form and the post requests do not seem to making it to the server (in production only).

what am i doing wrong?

UPDATES:

solution: crsf tokens need to be pushed ajax post requests (not gets) as of django 1.3

also, per the link provide below, the following javascript

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",
                                     $("#csrfmiddlewaretoken").val());
            }
        }
    });
```

needs to be changed as follows:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
                // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",
                                     $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val());
            }
        }
    });
```

the way the csrf token gets rendered in the form must have changed between 1.25 - 1.3??
regardless, it works. thanks for all your help everyone

Comment: Use firebug or webkit's inspector to see what happens with the request, i bet there's 500 error there.

Comment: actually i am getting 403 forbidden

Comment: ... is the user logged in that is trying to send that ajax form?

Comment: i do not have any user authentication system yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you directly access your javascript files from the production server?  Which Django version are you using in production?  If you are using 1.2.5+ in production, you will need to push the csrf token to the server during an AJAX post operation.

See [the release notes in 1.2.5](http://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2011/feb/08/security/) and [CSRF](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax)

To check your Django version:

```
import django
django.get_version()
```

Print the above in your production site or from the shell in your production server while making sure you are using the proper Python path.

Comment: $ python -c "import django; print django.get_version()" 1.3

Comment: ok so the solution was in fact that the CSRF token was not being pushed with the ajax request. one modification i had to make was the following (take from that link provided in the release notes of 1.2.5

Comment: Looks like you are using 1.3 in production.  Create a new virtualenv on your dev machine and install django 1.3.  Run your project from there and test the post ajax operation.  You might need to read more from the CSRF link I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears fine with a cursory glance, but I'll show you an example of my ajax form processing code in a hope it'll help with figuring out the error that's occurring. Though, what @dmitry commented should be your first debugging step - use firebug or the inspector to see if the ajax call returns an error.

```
// js (jQuery 1.5)
$(form).submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post(post_url, $(form).serialize())
              .success(function(data, status, jqxhr) {
                if (data.success) { // form was valid
                    $(form)
                    // other irrelevant code
                    .siblings('span')
                      .removeClass('error')
                      .html('Form Successful');
                } else { // form was invalid
                    $(form).siblings('span').addClass('error').html('Error Occurred');
                }
              })
              .error(function(jqxhr, status, error) { // server error
                $(form).siblings('span').addClass('error').html("Error: " + error);
              });
});


// django
class AjaxFormView(FormView):
    def ajax_response(self, context, success=True):
        html = render_to_string(self.template_name, context)
        response = simplejson.dumps({'success': success, 'html': html})
        return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/json", mimetype='application/json')


// view deriving from AjaxFormView

    def form_valid(self, form):
        registration = form.save()
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            context = {'competition': registration.competition }
            return self.ajax_response(context, success=True)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(registration.competition.get_absolute_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            context = { 'errors': 'Error Occurred'}
            return self.ajax_response(context, success=False)
        return render_to_response(self.template_name, {'errors':form.errors})
```

Actually, comparing the above to your code, you *may* need to set the content_type in your django view so that jQuery can understand and process the response. Note that the above is using django 1.3 class-based views, but the logic should be familiar regardless. I use `context.success` to signal if the form processing passed or failed - since a valid response (json) of any kind will signal the `jQuery.post` that the request was successful.

Comment: added content_type="application/json", mimetype='application/json' to my HttResponse, no dice though