# django - valueError

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I'm developing a web application where I'm stuck with a problem in one feature. You can check it out here http://qlimp.com  You can also use this for username/password: dummy/dummy

After login, please click the link **Go to cover settings** You will see a palette where you can upload images, enter some text.

When you upload the image, I've written an ajax request in jQuery which uploads the image to the server and shows fullpage background preview of that image.

JQuery

```
$('#id_tmpbg').live('change', function()
    {
    $("#ajax-loader").show();
    $("#uploadform").ajaxForm({success: showResponse}).submit();
    });

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  { 
    $.backstretch(responseText)
    $("#ajax-loader").hide();
}
```

So the problem here is, when I upload the image, it shows

```
ValueError at /cover/ 
The view cover.views.backgroundview didn't return an HttpResponse object. 
Request Method: POST Request URL: http://qlimp.com/cover/
```

I'm actually returning HttpResponse object in views.

Views.py:

```
@login_required
def backgroundview(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = BackgroundModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                g = BackgroundModel.objects.get(user=request.user)
            except BackgroundModel.DoesNotExist:
                data = form.save(commit=False)
                data.user = request.user
                data.save()
            else:
                if g.tmpbg != '' and g.tmpbg != g.background:
                    image_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(g.tmpbg))
                    try:
                        os.unlink(image_path)
                    except:
                        pass
                data = BackgroundModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=g).save()
            return HttpResponse(data.tmpbg.url)
    else:
        form = BackgroundModelForm()
        return render_to_response("cover.html", {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Models.py:

```
class BackgroundModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    background = models.ImageField(upload_to='backgrounds', null=True, blank=True)
    tmpbg = models.ImageField(upload_to='backgrounds', null=True, blank=True)

class BackgroundModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BackgroundModel
        exclude = ('user','background')
```

But these things are working on my computer(save the image and shows the background preview) but not in the production server. Why is it so?
I've uploaded the same code to the server.

Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: which OS u r using in local and which one for production?

Comment: Both Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on production

Comment: Is the form validating? Looking at the code if form.is_active() is False, nothing is returned.

Comment: I m not sure whether this will work or not but try to return HttpResponse in every condition. like you have not written else part of [ if form.is_valid() ] so write else part and return HttpResponse.And you are making ajax request so first store render_to_string in some string variable and then return that variable as [ return HttpResponse(stringvariable) ].

Comment: @Mikael I hope it is validating because there is no problem in my developement server. Still there are some more problems which I'm having in production. Why this difference from developement to production?

Comment: since you are using 12.04 in production. python may be latest 3.1 . so that can be your concern.

Comment: @PriyankPatel Oh! I'll check that one. Thanks!

Comment: @PriyankPatel Both are Python 2.7

Comment: Can you try to trace if is_valid is failing and what the error is?

Comment: @Mikael I tried. The image is not even getting stored in the server, which means it fails in entering the form.is_valid or is_ajax.

Comment: Try to see if you can output form.errors to see if you can spot anything there... also as a "dumb" question: is PIL installed on the production server?

Comment: Yes it is installed. Could you tell me that form.errors method in more detail?

Comment: form.errors is an attribute that will validate the form and display the errors found during validation.

Comment: You might have to push the CSRF token through the AJAX POST. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696561/django-posts-not-working

Comment: @Mikael Here is my ajax setup https://gist.github.com/2775157 Do I need to perform any modification there? Btw thanks for your help

Comment: @Mikael My Django version is 1.4 in production and 1.3.1 in the development.

Comment: @Mikael Will rebuilding the server and installing the same django version used on the development solve the problem?

Comment: I think you need to trace if is_ajax or is_valid is True to figure out where the issue is before rebuilding anything

Comment: @Mikael I'm using sqlite3 in production. Is that creating this problem? Because every code in production is perfectly working on my computer

Comment: @Mikael Yes I checked it. The problem is from `form.is_valid()` and it is true for `is_ajax`. Could you help me now? Thanks!

Comment: You need to log what error form.is_valid() gives by logging the output from form.errors to a file and post that output here

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning a response if the form is valid.

Comment: what abt this `HttpResponse()`?

Comment: It is in the true condition of the outer `if`; have two `if`, for the outer `if` you have a return for both conditions, but the inner `if` doesn't return a `HttpResponse` on all execution paths.

Comment: What changes I need to make? The code I've given is working on my computer.

Comment: you could put your 2nd to last line near the top ... `form = BackgroundModelForm()`, get rid of your last `else` and move your last line to the left (de-indent it)  ... `return render_to_response(   ...`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I'm using sqlite3 in production. Will that create this problem? Because every code in production is perfectly working on my computer.